# How to sort list based on nested object property

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am new to Java streams and I just want to sort the keys for my object.

So, I try something like this and it works

```
List<FooSelect> li= Arrays.stream(obj.getFoos().getFoo())  //Stream<Foo>
    .map(Foo::getSelect)                                   //Stream<FooSelect>
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(FooSelect::getFoosKey))   //Stream<FooSelect>
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This sorts it according to what I want.

But the result I get is in `List<FooSelect>` object, though I want it in `List<Foo>`.

How can I change the mapping after it is sorted?

I want to again change the response in

```
//Stream<Foo> after it is sorted.
```

I want something like

```
List<Foo> li = same result of code above;
```

---

```
Class : FooSelect
just has some String fields
string FooKey
string FooTKey
```

and getters and setters for that (one of them is getFoosKey by which I am sorting)

```
Class: Foo
private FooSelect select
private FooInsert insert

Foo(select, insert)

public FooSelect getSelect() {
return select; }
```

Same way setter.

Comment: @Aomine How can i do that ? I tried, but it gives me error only. Can you please just describe that line ?

Comment: show how `Foo` and `FooSelect` look like i.e. their definitions then it would make it easier for people to answer your post

Comment: `List<Foo> li = same result of code above;` => `List<FooSelect>`, can you show us, how is that possible?

Comment: @Aomine Updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lambda expression in `Comparator.comparing` instead of method reference

```
List<Foo> res = foos.stream()             
                    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(fo->fo.getSelect().getFooKey()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

For just sorting you don't even need stream

```
foos.sort(Comparator.comparing(fo->fo.getSelect().getFooKey()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `map`. The `map` changes the object in the stream. Update the sorted statement as

```
.sorted(Comparator.comparing(f -> f.getSelect().getFoosKey()))
```