# Sort object list based on custom object as one of field

Tags: java, java-8

```
public class Employee {

private String name;
private String id;
private Address address;

public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Employee setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }


    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Employee setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }


    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public Employee setName(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
        return this;
    }


}

public class Address{
    
    public String streetName;
    public String streetNumber;

public String getName() {
        return streetName;
    }

    public Address setStreetName(String streetName) {
        this.streetName = streetName;
        return this;
    }


    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Address setStreetNumber(String streetNumber) {
        this.streetNumber = streetNumber;
        return this;
    }

}
```

Employee is one of class as defined above and Address is one of data type for one of field for Employee. List needs to be sorted based on `streetName` which is part of `address` field of Employee.

This can be done using writing a custom comparator. I am looking for a way using java lambda to sort and get the sorted list?

Comment: `Collections.sort(employees,Comparator.comparing(employee -> employee.getAddress().getStreetName()));`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: you can check this link for the same type of question
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58223132/9024680

Comment: What did your search bring up? Also asking because this question has been asked and answered before.

Comment: I have been trying to use enum instead of switch and case and this is one of many condition where sorting needs to be done based on field. The way I wanted was not working with help I got from different posts. Hence had to ask question. I wrote something like: BYSTREETNAME("bystreetname", (a, b) -> a.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing((Function<? super Employee, ? extends String>) c -> c.getAddress().getStreetName(),
                b.equalsIgnoreCase("ascending")? Comparator.naturalOrder(): Comparator.reverseOrder())).collect(Collectors.toList()));

Answer (score 2):

You could create a comparator like below or the way @Hadi J does in the comment:

```
Comparator<Employee> byStreetName = (emp1, emp2) -> emp1.getAddress().getName().compareTo(
                                                    emp2.getAddress().getName());
```

and use it like :

```
myList.sort(byStreetName);
```

or if you are using streams

```
myList.stream().sorted(byStreetName)...
```

Comment: `Comparator<Employee> byStreetName = Comparator.comparing(emp -> emp.getAddress().getStreetName());`